# Implicit context and eigenclasses

Tags: ruby, eigenclass

I recently found an [interesting article](http://yugui.jp/articles/846) on implicit contexts in Ruby, and I found the experience quite mind opening.
I understood that Ruby holds a reference not only to `self` (the *default method receiver*), but also to the *current class* (also known as *default definee* or `` `klass' ``).

From the article, It should be correct to assume that `class` definition sets both `self` and the *current class* to the class that is being defined; as far as we consider *normal* method definition (i.e. not using the *dot syntax* to define singleton methods), in the context of method definition with `def`, `self` refers to the receiving object, and the *current class* isn't changed.

The reason i find safe to not consider the *dot syntax* for defining is that Ruby also offers an explicit way to open the eigenclass of a class, and the very thing I'm interested is understanding how these two implicit contexts are managed when opening a eigenclass.

Using `def` with the well known syntax for opening a eigenclass:

```
class << A
  p self

  def foo
    # ...
  end
end
```

defines foo as a *singleton method* of `A`, i.e. an *instance method* of its eigenclass (be it `A'`). This code also prints `#<Class:A>`, so is it correct to say that the `<<` syntax sets both `self` and the *current class* to `A'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it actually opens the block under the control of A'.
Also you can say that it works like class_eval of A'.

Comment: I found the comparison with `class_eval` really interesting. While these implementation details are usually hidden (and probably should be), i think they're needed to understand why, e.g., `self` is `A` and not `A'` inside of `foo`, but if you define a method inside of `foo`, it's defined into `A'` and not `A` (to even further stress the difference between `self` and the current class!). This also makes clear the fact that in the idiom `class Object; def eigen; class << self; self; end; end; end` to get the eigenclass, you need to explicitly open the eigenclass *inside* the def.

Comment: You can eigen class, but you wont be able to instantiate it. 
Also 1 more fact i would like to tell is that you can also define methods for eigen class too, which can be called with eigen class only... and this can be done by writing class<<self ;end; in control of eigen class...This is wonderful that we can create eigen class of eigen class.

Comment: Yes, i already noticed that it's possible to get the *eigenclass of an eigenclass of an...* even if this is hardly useful in everyday programming :) I noticed however things can get a bit messy if we consider the full class hierarchy of *higher grade* eigenclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you wrote is exactly the same as writing:

```
class A
  class << self
    def foo
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

the class << self syntax indicates that a block of definitions will follow, and this is going to go straight to the eigenclass of the object passed to <<. And yes, I said Object, not Class. Try this (provided the class definition above):

```
a = A.new
class << a
  def foo2
  end
end
a.singleton_methods
b = A.new
b.singleton_methods
```

this means, in this case, you are defining the method foo2 in the eigenclass of the object a. But this is the eigenclass of the object itself, not the class. So, further objects of the same class will not share this foo2 definition.

So what this means? Ruby is (or claims to be) a pure OO language. Everything is an object. An Object of a class defined by you is an Object. A Class defined by you is also an Object. Of type Class. Which inherits from Object. In Ruby, all objects have an eigenclass. Actually, the definition of "class methods" is just an interpretation of its concept. "Class Methods" are not really class methods, but methods defined in the eigenclass of the class. So, when you are calling a "class method", you are indeed calling an object method. This object just happens to be a class you defined. How you define eigenclass methods? Exactly the class << self syntax. The "self" in this context is whatever you passed as an argument to class <<.

Comment: Of course I'm well aware of this; however, the concept I'm trying to tackle is somehow a bit more obscure: the difference between `self` and what is sometimes called 'klass', i.e. the class on which `def` defines a method (cfr. with `define_method` that always work on `self`, instead). Thanks anyway for your clear explaination.

Comment: My apologies for not tackling the right issue. But what do you mean by 'klass' then? Technically this doesn't exist. As for self, I just take it as a scope in such meta block definitions.

Comment: You can read about it in the article I linked; basically, it refers to the class to which the methods defined with `def` are added. To better clarify: when using `instance_eval` and `class_eval` on an object, be it a class `A`, the value of `self` inside both the blocks associated with the two `eval`s is `A`. However `def` works differently inside the two blocks: this is because `'klass'` refers to `A` when using `class_eval`, to `A'` when using `instance_eval`. I'm interested with the mechanics of how this context is managed by Ruby.

Comment: An even more obvious example where the two differ is the top-level: at the top-level `self` is `main`, but the definition context is `Object` (and `private`, interestingly!)

Comment: I see. The way I see if, when doing class_eval on A you are defining methods in its definition, i.e. they are instance_methods of A (doing class A; def foo; ; end; end is the same as A = Class.new; A.class_eval do; def foo; ; end ; end (for both: A.instance_methods). By using instance_eval, you are not accessing A, but its singleton/eigenclass (maybe what you refer by A'). and A.instance_eval &block is the same as class << A &block. self in both cases will be the eigenclass (for both: A.singleton_methods).

Comment: and: in both cases, the value of self is A is shown as A, but it's actually not; i thinking this was a protection so that you can't instantiate the eigenclass (because then, this eigenclass would have to have an eigenclass of its own, which it can't).

Comment: class F ; def eigen ; class << self ; self ; end ; end ; end